# how to fire specific hangFire jobs not all jobs in my project

Tags: asp.net, .net, hangfire

I'm using hangFire Jobs and it works fine except that the jobs are more than the jobs I wanted in my code as follows:

```
public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
        {


              RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate( () =>  RecurringJobs(cancellationToken), Cron.Daily);

            //tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => dropdownsData.Degrees = (await connection.QueryAsync<LookUpsDTO>("select DEGREE_CODE  ID,  DEGREE_CODE Code, DEGREE_DESC LatinName, DEGREE_DESC ArabicName  from CDE_DEGREES", null, transaction)).AsList()));

            //RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => PendingStartSecondment(cancellationToken), Cron.MinuteInterval(10));

            //RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => PendingEndSecondment(cancellationToken), Cron.Daily);

            //RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => PendingStartTerminations(cancellationToken), Cron.MinuteInterval(10));

            return await next();
        }

        public async Task RecurringJobs(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            await this.PendingStartVactions(cancellationToken);

            await this.PendingEndVactions(cancellationToken);

            await this.PendingStartSecondment(cancellationToken);

            await this.PendingEndSecondment(cancellationToken);

            await this.PendingStartTerminations(cancellationToken);





        }
```

I have only these 5 methods to be fired daily. but in dashboard I have 40 recurring jobs and 105 scheduled jobs and all Jobs are 1387. I'm new at using it so I don't understand why all these jobs are taken into account.